# When it is usually taken as $\omega=v/r$, why in this particular case $\omega=v/3r$ is taken?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

[image]

> A circular disc of mass m and radius r is set into motion on a horizontal floor with a linear speed v in the forward direction and an angular speed w =v/3r in clockwise direction .Find magnitude of total angular momentum of the disc  about axis perpendicular to the plane of disc and passing through bottom most  point 'o' of the disc and fixed to ground?

Comment: At the point of contact there is relative motion between the disc and the floor, ie there is slipping.

Answer (score 2):

The angular velocity is related to the tangential speed $v_t$ by:

$$ \omega = \frac{v_t}{r} $$

However the velocity $v$ being used here is not the tangential speed. It is the linear velocity $v_l$ of the centre of mass of the disk relative to the floor. The question has chosen a value for the angular velocity of the disk that appears similar to the equation linking angular velocity and tangential speed:

$$ \omega = \frac{v_l}{3r} $$

but this means only that $v_l \ne v_t$ i.e. that the disk is slipping over the floor as it translates.

Answer (score 1):

$\omega=\frac{v}{r}$ is used for rotating without slipping. Your disc is rotating and slipping. So, it is possible that $\omega=\frac{v}{3r}$.